# Object initialized via resolve is not "watched"?

Tags: angularjs

I need help to understand the concept of "watching" the changes of an object and updating it in the view.

In my particular case, the object is initialized via the view's resolve then assign to scope's parameter withing the controller.

My expectation is that somehow if I update the original object again then it should change the value printed out in the view

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        template: 'hello {{ user.name }}',
        controller: 'userController',
        resolve: {
          user: function () {
            return {name: 'john'}
          }
        }
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);

myApp.controller('userController', function($scope, user) {

    $scope.user = user;

    // I thought the object is supposed to be watched by reference but it is not
    user = {name: 'doe'}

});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/w7woYVYB6GwCiJpWGWB4?p=preview

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it

Edit for more clarification:

It's my fault to skip the reason behind all this. My resolve actually looks like this:

```
resolve: {
              user: function () {
                return userService.get();
              }
            }
```

As you can see, I'm returning an object to resolve (which is a property defined inside the userService). Now, my hope is that if I can simply call userService.update();  in my controller then somehow the $scope.user still pointing to the same object will update automatically. I guess not....

```
userService.update();
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to implement the $watch functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple. $scope.user points to a different object than what user points to after the call `user = {name: 'doe'}`

The fix is either one of them

```
$scope.user={name:'doe';}
```

or

```
$scope.user.name='doe';
```

**Update:** If the service updates the data and controllers want to get notify the approach to take would be to raise events on $rootSscope.
In the service you can do

```
$rootScope.$emit('event.userUpdate',{user:user});
```

In the controller you can catch this event with

```
$rootScope.$on('event.userUpdate',function(evt, args) {
   //args should have he update user data, to rebind.
});
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is that this user is supposed to be updated via a service, so I would prefer to somehow simply update user and the scope will reflect that, any solution at all?

Comment: As long as the service updates the same user object, everything would work fine.

Comment: Thanks Chandermani, I updated my question for some more info, please let me know if I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: An angularjs service is a factory function and as such is fired only once (when the controller is instantiated). You can implement a $watch function to monitor when a change happens and then call the service function again.

Comment: Chandermani is completely correct. His approach is probably what you want. You fire a $emit or $broadcast event when a user has changed and in all interested controllers watch with $on for changes and respond accordingly.

Comment: thank you, I chose to use the solution you suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, then this should work:

```
myApp.controller('userController', function($scope, user) {

    $scope.user = user;

    $scope.user = {name: 'doe'}

});
```

Note the line: `$scope.user = {name: 'doe'}` instead of `user = {name: 'doe'}`

Here is your modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SPOmR41p11xkkbmE96uI?p=info).

As you edited your question, I also updated my answer to show you how to implement the $watch functionality. In this case we are watching for a change on a variable willChange and changing the user accordingly. Here the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fxurmHS1b0yXW3FPUWO?p=preview).

Comment: thank you zszep, I updated my question with more info